# Downloading large zip via wget into vm corrupts file

Tags: macos, centos, wget, vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to automate a download of a 3 gig file into a vm managed by using vagrant and puppet. The file downloads, and appears to be the full three gigs, but the md5 I download with it consistently fails the md5sum test. Conversely, if I download it outside the vm on my mac (with wget) into a shared folder with the vm, and then ssh into the vm and check the md5 it downloads fine. Any suggestions?

Code example:

```
wget http://mymachine.com/archive.zip && wget http://mymachine.com/archive.md5
md5sum -c archive.md5
```

What I'm running:
Local Machine: Mac OSX Mavericks
VM OS: CentOS 6.4
Vagrant Version: 1.3.5
VirtualBox Version: 4.3.4

Answer (score 1):

I would run the problematic wget with the -d flag on its own.

Review http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Reporting-Bugs for more info on finding out what is happening for wget.

This may give you some clues as to why this does not work in the VirtualBox VM

Then you will need to review https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=48476
to review the steps required to query Virtual Box logs to report probelems with it.

Finally, you could try older versions of Virtual Box to see if the problem still occurs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a very similar configuration and downgrading to VirtualBox 4.2.24 works for me as a workaround.

- Host Hardware: MacBook Pro
- Host OS: Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.2)
- Guest OS: CentOS 6.4
- Vagrant: 1.4.3
- VirtualBox: Tried 4.3.6, 4.3.8, 4.3.10 and they all resulted in corrupted wget downloads inside the guest OS for large zip files (600MB - 1.2GB)

Not sure what is going on as I thought VirtualBox 4.3.+ added better Mavericks support.